# Monitor the count of a mutable array in swift.

Tags: ios, swift, nsmutablearray

Hi i want to monitor the count of a mutable array in swift. Whenever i add/remove objects to array, i need a notification regarding the count. Does KVO helps here?, if not what are the other possible solutions. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You could wrap it inside some object and implement pub/sub or observer pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use [KVO in Swift](https://medium.com/proto-venture-technology/the-state-of-kvo-in-swift-aa5cb1e05cba) by using the `dynamic` keyword. However, for your particular problem—why not try using a [property observer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-XID_390):

```
var mutableArray: [AnyObject]? {
    didSet {
        println("count changed from \(oldValue.count) to \(newValue.count)")
    }
}
```

Comment: i have a mutable array like var mutableArray = NSMutableArray() . how can i implement on this?